# Wordpress REST API fails with Python requests on MacOS, works on Windows

Tags: python, wordpress, rest, python-requests

I've written a simple Python script to upload an image to a WP site:

```
import requests
import base64

BASE_URL = "https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2"

media = {
    "file": open("image.png", "rb"),
    "caption": "a media file",
    "description": "some media file"
}
creds = "wp_admin_user" + ":" + "app password"
token = base64.b64encode(creds.encode())
header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Authorization":"Basic " + token.decode("utf-8")
}
r = requests.post(BASE_URL + "/media", headers=header, files=media)

print(r)

if r.status_code >= 400:
    pprint(r.json())
```

When using Python 3.7 on Windows, everything works as expected: I get a `<Response [201]>` reply and I can see the image in my site's media library.

When running the exact same script on a Mac, it fails with a 503 reply (`he server is temporarily busy, try again later!`) from the WP server:

```
<Response [503]>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
<title> 503 Service Unavailable
</title></head>
<body style="color: #444; margin:0;font: normal 14px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; height:100%; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="height:auto; min-height:100%; ">     <div style="text-align: center; width:800px; margin-left: -400px; position:absolute; top: 30%; left:50%;">
        <h1 style="margin:0; font-size:150px; line-height:150px; font-weight:bold;">503</h1>
<h2 style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;">Service Unavailable
</h2>
<p>The server is temporarily busy, try again later!</p>
</div></div></body></html>
```

The MacOS is running Python 3.9.1

I can run the script again on Windows ten times, and it always works. I've searched the internets for the error and it's usually a WP configuration error, which doesn't seem to be the case here as the script works on Windows.

Any help is much appreciated!